# How to get HTTP request Accept Header in android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, http, android-webview, http-accept-header

Wanted to get `WebView` browser properties in android.

Able to get properties like navigator.userAgent, screen.width, screen.height etc.

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("navigator.javaEnabled()", new ValueCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
                Log.v("TAG", "JavaEnabled : " + value);
            }
        });
```

Along with this looking forward to get HTTP request Accept header in android WebView.

Is there any way to get same?
Any help is welcome

Answer (score 1):

You can add headers while loading URL to `Webview` like:

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("Content-Type", "applicatoin/json");
webView.loadUrl(url, headers);
```

You can check WebView current headers :

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                Log.d("WebView", "RequestHeaders :"+request.getRequestHeaders());
                return null;
            }
        });
```